# ServiceConnect not working on instagram

Tags: social-media

I've been trying to connect Instagram to WM.
But when I evaluate the basic command

```
ServiceConnect["Instagram"]
```

I get

```
ServiceConnect::disc: Due to restrictions added by Instagram, this service is currently not available.
```

Is this something I can fix in anyway? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe so. I spoke with WRI about this almost a year ago. They told me Instagram has restricted their API.